# Using sockets in a Swift 3 iPhone app

Tags: ios, tcp, swift3

I have recently started to learn Swift 3 and I need to somehow get it to talk to a python program running on a Raspberry Pi. I have seen several libraries like Socket.IO that can achieve this however I'm not sure where to start with these. How do I go about creating a socket in Swift 3. I do require 2 way communication so would I be correct in saying that a socket would be the correct way to go?

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the platform you're using.  Since you're on iOS I'd suggest leveraging InputStream/OutputStream.  The parent Stream protocol provides an interface to create input/output streams on a socket, it leverages CFSockets underneath and has a nice Swift 3 interface

```
var inputStream: InputStream?
var outputStream: OutputStream?
Stream.getStreamsToHost(withName: "thing.local", port: 9090, inputStream: &inputStream, outputStream: &outputStream)
```

In case anyone else stumbles in wondering about sockets, if you're /not/ on iOS, macOS, etc., Swift CoreFoundation is still incomplete and doesn't have Stream.getStreamsToHost implemented properly (or a lot of other stuff unfortunately :/)  However you can make posix sockets since Swift can use C

```
#if os(OSX) || os(iOS) || os(watchOS) || os(tvOS)
  import Darwin
#elseif os(Linux) || os(FreeBSD) || os(PS4) || os(Android)
  import Glibc
#endif

let sock = socket(AF_INET, Int32(SOCK_STREAM.rawValue), 0)
var addr = sockaddr_in(sin_family: sa_family_t(AF_INET),
                       sin_port: in_port_t(htons(UInt16(port))),
                       sin_addr: hostAddr,
                       sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
let addrPtr = withUnsafePointer(to: &addr){ UnsafePointer<sockaddr>(OpaquePointer($0)) }

let connected = connect(sock, addrPtr, UInt32(MemoryLayout<sockaddr_in>.size))
```

Of course that's all quite unpleasant to read and not very Swifty, but fear not head on over to github and look around at the plethora of Socket implementations.  All of the major server-side-swift projects (Perfect, IBM Kitura, Vapor, Zewo, Noze, etc) have some simple socket and/or SSL Socket implementations that you can use, or if you want you can write your own and wrap C sockets like they all do anyway.

A fun exercise even on iOS would be to expand your GCD knowledge and write a GCD based socket using either DispatchSource or DispatchIO (DispatchSource is useful for servers listening, IO is useful for any generic async in-order IO to a file descriptor or the like, and a socket is just a file descriptor so...)